# How to get only exact attributes from list of classes

Tags: scala

How to get only exact attributes from list of classes, e.g.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val a = Person("a", 1)
val b = Person("b", 1)
val persons = List(a, b)

val names = ???

assertEquals(List("a", "b"), names)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
scala> val names = persons.map(_.name)
names: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

Or this if you want access to more than one field at the same time:

```
scala> val names = persons.map{ case Person(name, age) => name }
names: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

Comment: Good, thanks, you also may add this `val names = persons.map{ case p:Person => p.name }` to your answer

Comment: @yons88, `case p:Person => p.name` is just a more verbose way of writing `_.name`.  The type annotation is unnecessary since Scala already knows it's operating on a `List[Person]`, and `p => p.name` is just a more verbose version of `_.name`.

Answer (score 0):

you also can do 
    `for { person <- persons } yield person.name`
 which is basically  the same thing as the map